# CSS 3D animation, how?

Tags: javascript, html, css, 3d, css-animations

I would like to animate things in 3D space. I know this is possible with CSS and HTML5, but I can't find a good tutorial for practical use!

I found [this website](http://www.typeofnan.com) as an example. You can select text etc. All the time.
Can somebody give a very easy to understand and little example how this works? I see the source code but I don't really understand it…

Is this CSS3 or HTML5 or both?

How much JavaScript do I need?

Which browsers support this?

Comment: You can take a look at webgl if you want. http://www.ibiblio.org/e-notes/webgl/webgl.htm which is javascript

Comment: This question is overly broad. You should really restrict the issue to something specific. For instance: how do I animate a spinning cube in HTML5?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Its all css3 and javascript.  Just inspect the site in your favorite inspector, dig into the dom, and you'll see something like

```
-webkit-perspective: none;
-webkit-perspective-origin: 200px 200px;
-webkit-transform: matrix3d(-0.9386958080415784, -0.197569680458564, 0.2825179663820851, 0, 0, 0.8194947008605812, 0.5730867606754029, 0, -0.34474654452969944, 0.537954139890128, -0.7692562404101148, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1);
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
-webkit-transition-delay: 0s;
-webkit-transition-duration: 16s;
-webkit-transition-property: all;
-webkit-transition-timing-function: linear;
```

how much javascript you need depends on how you want to implement it.  It can be 'a lot' or 'a little'.

The more modern a browser, the better the change it will run well. [Check here](http://caniuse.com/#search=3d) to see which browsers support what.

Comment: I copied that in my example, how can I move it automatically?

Comment: “The latest versions of all the browsers should support transforms.” — I don’t think that’s true of 3D transforms: see http://caniuse.com/#search=3d.

Answer (score 86):

There are two parts to this.

1. The first one is about *building* the 3D shape.
2. The second one involves *animating* it (and this is the simple part).

---

## UPDATE AUGUST 2019

This is a really old answer and I'll leave the meat of the original below, just removing the links that don't work anymore.

But since I wrote this, both my coding abilities and browsers have progressed, so if you want to build a CSS cube in a more efficient fashion, check out this article I wrote on the topic:

## [Simplifying CSS Cubes with Custom Properties](https://css-tricks.com/simplifying-css-cubes-custom-properties/)

---

I'll go through each one of them in detail, but first I'll briefly answer the three questions you've asked at the end.

> is this css3 or html5 or both?

It's CSS3. CSS [**3D transforms**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-function) and [**keyframe animations**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/@keyframes).

> how much javascript do I need?

Well, if you don't want to create 3D shape itself with JavaScript, then you don't need any JavaScript to animate it. Any browser that [supports 3D transforms](http://caniuse.com/#feat=transforms3d) also [supports keyframe animations](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-animation) and, [*if a browser supports keyframe animations, then you probably want to use those instead of jQuery (and maybe even your own custom JS) animations*](http://dev.opera.com/articles/view/css3-vs-jquery-animations/).

> which browsers support this?

Things didn't look good two years ago, but they're getting better...

**✓ Chrome**, **Safari**, **Firefox** (though Firefox 3D animations are jiggly and not nice to my CPU... I do have a 6-year-old old laptop, it's true) **Opera 15+ (WebKit)** support 3D transforms. And of course keyframe animations.

Firefox supports everything unprefixed, Chrome/Safari/Opera need the `-webkit-` prefix - **update**: Chrome 36+ and Opera 23+ support them unprefixed as well, so it's only Safari left now. I won't be using any prefixes in the answer or in the demo ([**`-prefix-free`**](http://leaverou.github.com/prefixfree/) takes care of things there). **Another update**: Safari 9 unprefixes transforms.

**✗** 3D transforms were not supported by **Opera** before switching to WebKit.

**✗ IE up to and including 9** don't support 3D transforms. **IE10** and **IE11** support 3D transforms, but *do not support nesting of 3D transformed elements* (cannot create realistic looking 3D shapes via applying 3D transforms on both parent and child elements, as 3D transformed children of a 3D transformed parent get flattened into the plane of the parent). **Update**: Edge now supports nesting of 3D transformed elements.

---

Alright, I hope that clears a few things. Now...

## 1 Building a CSS cube.

### 1.2 What is a cube and starting off with the HTML

First of all, try to picture a cube. Maybe [**this link**](http://www.mathopenref.com/cube.html) helps? Or let's have an image here as well.

[image: cube]

It has 6 square faces. 1 top, 1 bottom; 1 in front, 1 in the back; 1 left, 1 right. This means that the HTML is simply:

```
<ul class='cube'>
    <li class='face'></li>
    <li class='face'></li>
    <li class='face'></li>
    <li class='face'></li>
    <li class='face'></li>
    <li class='face'></li>
</ul>
```

You first put some regularity into the faces, give them *equal* `width` and `height`, position them absolutely so that they're all stacked one on top of the other, give them different backgrounds, they don't mind that. You can give them some padding, put some dummy text into them, whatever...

Now comes the interesting part: moving them so that they form a cube in space. You do that using 3D transforms.

### 1.2 The Coordinate System

Consider this 3D coordinate system:

[image: 3D coordinate system]

Initially, all the 6 faces are all exactly where you see the blue square, in the `xOy` plane (where `O` is the intersection of the 3 axes).

Pay attention to the direction of the `y-axis`. Coming from a mathematical background, this seemed a bit weird to me at first, but this is how the coordinate system is for the screen.

In 2D, the origin `O` is at the top left corner, so the `+` (positive direction) of the `x-axis` points right and the `+` of the `y-axis` points down.

#### 1.2.a Translations along the axes

So a translation of a positive value along the `x-axis` (for example, `translateX(10px)`) moves the element to which it is applied to the right (towards the `+` of the `x-axis`), while a translation of a negative value along the `x-axis` (something like `translateX(-10px)`) moves it to the left.

Similarly, a translation of a positive value along the `y-axis` (like `translateY(10px)`) moves the element down (towards the `+` of the `y-axis`), while a translation of a negative value along the `y-axis` (like `translateY(-10px)`) moves it up.

Now add another dimension. With the `z-axis`. The `+` (positive direction) of the `z-axis` comes out of the screen, towards you. So a translation of a positive value along the `z-axis` (like `translateZ(10px)`) moves the element forward (towards the `+` of the `z-axis` and towards you), while a translation of a negative value along the `z-axis` (like `translateZ(-10px)`) moves it backward (away from you).

#### 1.2.b Rotations around the axes

Rotations of positive angle values (for example, `rotate(15deg)` - note that if the rotation axis is not specified, then it is assumed to be the `z-axis`) in CSS are clockwise and rotations of negative angle values (like `rotate(-15deg)`) are counter-clockwise.

And clockwise means clockwise as seen from the `+` of the axis around which you rotate the element.

So a positive rotation around the `x-axis` means a clockwise rotation in the `yOz plane` as seen from the `+` of the `x-axis`, which is at the right.

A positive rotation around the `y-axis` means a clockwise rotation in the `zOx plane` (the horizontal plane) as seen from the `+` of the `y-axis`, which is at the bottom.

A positive rotation around the `z-axis` means a clockwise rotation in the `xOy plane` (the plane of the screen) as seen from the `+` of the `z-axis`, which is how you naturally see the screen.

### 1.3 Put the faces in the right positions in order to form the cube

#### 1.3.1 Put one face at the *front*

This means translating it forwards (in the positive direction) along the `z-axis`. What is this? A `translateZ` of a positive value. What value? Well, it should be half the `width` (or the `height`, doesn't matter, it's a square, they're equal).

Suppose I have the `width: 16em;`

Then in this case, you translate the face forward (along the positive `z-axis`) by `16em/2 = 8em`. In CSS, that's

```
.face:nth-child(1) { transform: translateZ(8em); }
```

**Note**: *The translate `transform` moves the entire coordinate system of the element that is translated (and consequently, the `transform-origin` for any subsequent transforms).*

#### 1.3.2 Put the second face at the *back*

That's simple, right? Just a translate along the `z-axis`, by the same value in the opposite direction, right? `.face:nth-child(2) { transform: translateZ(`***`-8em`***`); }`, right?

Well... actually... only if you don't want to put any content on that face. Or if you don't want to have as a background an image for which it matters which is left and which is right.

*Each of these squares that make up the cube has a front and a back*. The front is the one towards the positive direction of the `z-axis`; the one that "looks at you from the computer screen". If you put text there, it flows normally on the front. But it looks vertically mirrored on the back.

That's why the first thing that you should do is to rotate the second square face by 180° around the vertical axis (`y-axis`). After doing that, you can then translate this second square face along the `z-axis` in order to move it to the back.

The *translate value is again positive* in this case. Just like the translate `transform` *moves* the coordinate system of the element that is translated, the rotate `transform`... well... *rotates* it. This means that *after `rotateY(180deg)` is applied, the **`+`** of the `z-axis` points towards the back* (not towards the front anymore).

So the CSS that rotates and then translates the second face into its position on the cube is:

```
.face:nth-child(2) { transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(8em); }
```

**Note**: the cube is a really simple 3D shape, but one CSS property that I find really useful to check whether I've rotated faces the right way is [**`backface-visibility`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/backface-visibility). If I set it to `hidden` and I don't see the rotated element, it means that I'm looking at it from the back.

#### 1.3.3 Put the third face to the *right*

First of all, its front has to "look" towards the right. This means that it has to be rotated around the `y-axis` so that the `+` of the `z-axis` ends up pointing towards the right and then it has to be translated along the positive `z-axis` by the same positive value (`8em` in this case) that is half the length  of the side of the square.

Rotated by what angle? Well, 90°, which means the CSS needed is:

```
.face:nth-child(3) { transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(8em); }
```

#### 1.3.4 Put the fourth face to the *left*

First rotate it by `90°`, but *the other way*, to make its front "look" towards the left. "The other way" means `rotateY(-90deg)`, then apply the same old `translateZ(8em)`. In one CSS line:

```
.face:nth-child(4) { transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(8em); }
```

#### 1.3.5 Put the fifth face at the *top*

First rotate it by `90°` around the `x-axis` and then translate along the `z-axis` (which points up after the rotation). CSS:

```
.face:nth-child(5) { transform: rotateX(90deg) translateZ(8em); }
```

#### 1.3.6 Put the sixth (and last!) face at the *top*

Rotate it by `90°` the other way around the `x-axis`, then translate it along the `z-axis` (which points down after the rotation). CSS:

```
.face:nth-child(6) { transform: rotateX(-90deg) translateZ(8em); }
```

### 1.4 Perspective and realistic looking 3D shapes

All the faces of the cube are now in place. But this won't look like much of a 3D shape unless the faces that are closer seem bigger than those that are further away. The CSS property that takes care of this is called [**`perspective`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/perspective) and is applied on the  parent of the elements which have 3D transforms applied on them.

It still won't look like much of a 3D shape if you look perpendicular to the center of the front face because you won't see any of the other faces. To fix this, you need to rotate the cube itself in 3D. And this is why it's important that the browser allows nesting of 3D transformed elements.

You enable nesting of 3D transformed elements with [**`transform-style: preserve-3d;`**](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/CSS/transform-style) on the parent element (`.cube` in this case). Unfortunately, IE10/11 do not support the `preserve-3d` value for the `transform-style` property (only support the `flat` value), so you cannot have a realistic looking cube in IE yet (unless you [take the 3D transforms applied on the cube and chain them before the transforms applied for each face, which means one set of keyframes for each face if you want to animate the cube as a whole](http://davidwalsh.name/3d-transforms)).

**Update**: `transform-style: preserve-3d` now landing in IE as well.

**Note**: If you also apply 3D transforms on the `.cube`, then you should move the `perspective` property on the parent of the `.cube`.

## 2 Animating the CSS cube

That's done using just the regular keyframe animations for the `.cube` element. Let's say you want to rotate it:

```
@keyframes ani { to { transform: rotate3d(5, 12, 13, 360deg); } }
```

You can have multiple keyframes, with rotations around different axes, but this is the basic idea.

Comment: that's some awesome work. I'd be interested in the Maths for this. Didn't find it on your blog though;)

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what you mean. I thought the maths was in the answer and there is no blog.

Comment: @AndreMeinhold Why don't you change accepted answer for this much more helpful answer?

Comment: @Ana Could you please update the links? they're not working