# creating a moving 3d box with CSS transitions and Javascript

Tags: javascript, css, 3d, transition, translate

I have been playing with CSS trying to create a 3d box that you can select the face with vanilla javascript.

It is simply changing the className of the box divs and using the transition property to smoothly transition between locations.

here is a jsfiddle to show a working example http://jsfiddle.net/synthet1c/VdDmA/1/

It looks cool at the moment but it is not quite behaving the way I want... Does anyone know how I can keep the box solid when it is going through it's transition? currently if the face is going from 360deg to 90deg the face will rotate 270deg in the wrong direction. I understand why it's doing it but can't make a workaround for it.

I added all the browser prefixes but have only used it on firefox.

cheers for any advice,

Andrew
    #right, #back, #left, #front
    {
    height: 150px;
    width: 150px;
    position: absolute;
    border: 1px solid rgba(200,200,200,0.7);
    background-color: rgba(0,0,255,0.5);
    margin: 0px;
    }

```
.right{
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translatez(75px) translatex(-75px);
    transition: all 4s;
}

.back{
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translatez(0px) translatex(0px);
    transition: all 4s;
}

.left{
    transform: rotateY(270deg) translatez(75px) translatex(70px);
    transition: all 4s;
}

.front{
    transform: rotateY(0deg) translatez(150px) translatex(0px);
    transition: all 4s;
}
```

```
var id = function(elem){
    var theId = document.getElementById(elem);
    return theId;
}

function button1(){
    id('front').className = 'front';
    id('right').className = 'right';
    id('back').className = 'back';
    id('left').className = 'left';
}

function button2(){
    id('front').className = 'right';
    id('right').className = 'back';
    id('back').className = 'left';
    id('left').className = 'front';
}   

function button3(){
    id('front').className = 'back';
    id('right').className = 'left';
    id('back').className = 'front';
    id('left').className = 'right';
}   

function button4(){
    id('front').className = 'left';
    id('right').className = 'front';
    id('back').className = 'right';
    id('left').className = 'back';
}
```

Comment: Despite your best efforts, this doesn't work in Opera.

Comment: I'm not too solid of a CSS guy, but from the looks of it, you're approach is a little weird. Right now you are changing the class of each individual face of the square AKA animating each face individually. it would be better to set up each face with the proper x,y,z chords, and then perform your animation on a container div (a.k.a. rotate them all on the same Y axis) - better because the you're just animating the solid object, not making each face of the object chase each other.

Comment: that's a good idea.. I'll give it a go now and post back with the results.. thanks keith

Comment: no luck unfortunately... it will happily rotate the z axis but y and x are not working.. the z axis only flips the box clockwise with the current face remaining..

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It's actually pretty simple. You just need to do a check to see whether the difference, let's call it `dif`, in absolute value between the angle you're currently at and the angle you want to get to is over `180°` and if it is, you rotate by `360°` minus `dif` in absolute value, the direction of the rotation being given by the sign of `dif`.

I've also made some changes to the CSS, and if you want to understand more about how you can create a realistic looking cube, [**you can check my (really) detailed answer to a similar question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812196/css-3d-animation-how/14421939#14421939).

## [demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/4600310)

**HTML**:

```
<div class='buttons'>
    <button class='btn'>Front</button>
    <button class='btn'>Left</button>
    <button class='btn'>Back</button>
    <button class='btn'>Right</button>
</div>
<div class='house'>
    <div class='face front'>Front</div>
    <div class='face back'>Back</div>
    <div class='face right'>Right</div>
    <div class='face left'>Left</div>
</div>
```

Relevant **CSS**:

```
body /* or parent of .house */ { perspective: 45em; }
.house { position: relative; transform-style: preserve-3d; transition: 1s; }
.house, .face { width: 10em; height: 10em; }
.face {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    padding: 1em;
}
.front { transform: translateZ(5em); background: rgba(255, 165, 0, .75); }
.back { 
    transform: rotateY(180deg) translateZ(5em);
    background: rgba(30, 144, 255, .75);
}
.right {
    transform: rotateY(90deg) translateZ(5em);
    background: rgba(220, 20, 60, .75);
}
.left {
    transform: rotateY(-90deg) translateZ(5em);
    background: rgba(127, 255, 0, .75);
}
```

**JavaScript**:

```
(function(){
    var btnsEl = document.querySelector('.buttons'), currentAngle = 0;
    btnsEl.addEventListener('click', function(e){
        var b = e.target.innerHTML.toLowerCase(), 
            house = document.querySelector('.house'), 
            btns = {'front': 0, 'left': 90, 'back': 180, 'right': -90}, 
            dif = btns[b] - currentAngle%360;
        if(!e.target.classList.contains('btn') || dif === 0) return;
        currentAngle += (Math.abs(dif) > 180) ? 
                        (Math.abs(dif) - 360)*Math.abs(dif)/dif : 
                        dif;
        house.style['-webkit-transform'] = 'rotateY(' + currentAngle + 'deg)';
        house.style['transform'] = 'rotateY(' + currentAngle + 'deg)';
    }, false); 
}());
```

---

Also, you can do a rotating 3D box with pure CSS. However, the > `180°` rotation problem can only be solved with JavaScript.

### [pure CSS version of the demo](http://dabblet.com/gist/4600036)