# Effect of bottom view for a text using CSS

Tags: css

Whether it is possible tilt, rotate, shrink 3d text? I want to create an **effect of bottom view**  on my text (or if text lies on a table) using only CSS. Is it possible? I do not mean the animation, only static effect. I can do it in the 3dsMAX or PhotoShop, but I want to know how it can be implemented in CSS.

I have:

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHxVr/1/)

[image]

I want:

[image]

I got a little bit this effect (due to the large shadow). But I want to make it more clear and explicit. Further increase in the shade does not enhance the effect. **I need to tilt and compress vertically my text**. What styles can help me in this?

I would be grateful for any ideas!

My shadow styles:

```
text-shadow: 0px 0px 0 rgb(221,120,128),
             -1px 1px 0 rgb(215,114,122),
             -2px 2px 0   rgb(209,108,116),
             -3px 3px 0 rgb(203,102,110),
             -4px 4px 0 rgb(197,96,104),
             -5px 5px 0 rgb(191,90,98),
             -6px 6px 0 rgb(185,84,92),
             -7px 7px 0 rgb(178,77,85),
             -8px 8px 0 rgb(172,71,79),
             -9px 9px 0 rgb(166,65,73),
             -10px 10px 0 rgb(160,59,67),
             -11px 11px 0 rgb(154,53,61),
             -12px 12px 0 rgb(148,47,55),
             -13px 13px 0 rgb(142,41,49),
             -14px 14px 0 rgb(136,35,43),
             -15px 15px 0 rgb(130,29,37),
             -16px 16px 15px rgba(0,0,0,0.6),
             -16px 16px 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
             0px 0px 15px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
```

}

Comment: Have you tried `transform:rotateX(60deg) skewX(5deg);` ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

that is not easy i think you will need js for that,unfortunately [css text-shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiMNB.png) property is only 2 dimensional. Here is a quick example, use your keyboard to controll the angle

## *0- REAL 3D USING ONLY CSS cross browser compatibility solution(prefixfree)*

For Cross-browser gradients `(NO -webkit-,-moz-,-ms-)`

save your time using [LeaVerou/prefixfree](http://leaverou.github.io/prefixfree/)

you can find a [CDN Version here](http://cdnjs.com/)

[<kbd>3D DEMO with prefixfree & CSS only</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/YQA68/1/)

```
figure {
  transform-origin:center center;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transform: rotate3d(-1,0,0,-72deg);
}
```

[image]

## *1- REAL 3D USING JQUERY cross browser compatibility solution(prefixfree)*

[<kbd>3D DEMO with Jquery</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/YQA68/2/)

MARKUP

```
<figure></figure>
```

JS

```
var shadowLength = 40;
for(var i = 0;i < shadowLength; i++){
    var layer = $("<h1>3D TEXT</h1>").css("transform", "translateZ(-"+i+"px)");
    $("figure").append(layer);
}
```

CSS

```
* { box-sizing:border-box; }

:root{
  background-color: #00dbba;
  overflow:hidden;
  text-align:center;
}

figure {
  transform-origin:center center;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transform: rotate3d(-1,0,0,-72deg);
}

h1:first-child{
    color:white;
}
h1 {
  display:block;
  width:100%;
  padding:40px;
  line-height:1.5;
  font:900 8em 'Concert One', sans-serif;
  text-transform:uppercase;
  position:absolute;
  color:#51B3A3;
}
```

you can now choose the position by changing the value of `rotateZ(Value deg) rotateX(Value deg) rotateY(Value deg)` to get the perfect position.

```
figure {
  transform-origin:center center;
  transform-style:preserve-3d;
  transform: rotateZ(0deg) rotateX(70deg) rotateY(-12deg);
}
```

[image]

## *deep understanding css3D*

Read [how Nesting 3D Transformed Elements Works](http://davidwalsh.name/3d-transforms)

and don't miss [[CSSconf.eu 2013] Ana-Maria Tudor: Maths-powered transforms for creating 3D shapes](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=w9HeWBH_kvg)

if you need more, read

1- [css-3d-animation-how](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9812196/css-3d-animation-how/14421939#14421939)

2- [Ana-Maria Tudor on stackoverflow](http://careers.stackoverflow.com/anatudor)

## *2- REAL 3D*

[<kbd>3D DEMO with animation</kbd>](http://codepen.io/kougiland/pen/Lafni)

```
figure#figure3d {
  -webkit-transform: rotateX(54deg) scale(1) skew(10deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform-origin:center center;
  -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
}
```

[image]

you can remove the span if you don't like the animation at the beginning

```
span{
   display:none;/*comment me to remove the animation*/
}
```

## *3- IN GENERAL*

[<kbd>3D DEMO with animation</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/7RRHn/light/)

or change the angle  like this

```
-webkit-transform:rotate3d(-1,1,0,40deg);
```

[<kbd>3D DEMO without animation</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/t4734/)

```
#figure3d span {
color:silver;
    -webkit-text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #c0c0c0, 0px 2px 0px #b0b0b0, 0px 3px 0px #a0a0a0, 0px 4px 0px #909090, 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -moz-text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #c0c0c0, 0px 2px 0px #b0b0b0, 0px 3px 0px #a0a0a0, 0px 4px 0px #909090, 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
    -ms-text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #c0c0c0, 0px 2px 0px #b0b0b0, 0px 3px 0px #a0a0a0, 0px 4px 0px #909090, 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);
     text-shadow: 0px 1px 0px #c0c0c0, 0px 2px 0px #b0b0b0, 0px 3px 0px #a0a0a0, 0px 4px 0px #909090, 0px 5px 10px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.6);

  }

* { -webkit-box-sizing:border-box; }


figure#figure3d {
  -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg) scale(1) skew(0deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
  -webkit-transform-origin:center center;
  -webkit-transform-style:preserve-3d;
}
```

## *4- USING ONLY CSS*

the max you can do using text-shadow only ist something like this

```
#figure3d {
-webkit-transform: rotateX(65deg) scale(1) skew(10deg) translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);
-webkit-transform-origin: center center;
-webkit-transform-style: preserve-3d;
font-size:3.6em;
  letter-spacing:10px;
  font-family: 'Alfa Slab One', cursive;
font-weight:900;
    color:white;
text-shadow: -1px 1px 0 #51B3A3, 
    -2px 2px 0 #51B3A3, 
    -2px 3px 0 #51B3A3, 
    -2px 5px 0 #51B3A3,
    -2px 7px 0 #51B3A3,
    -2px 8px 0 #51B3A3,
    -2px 10px 0 #51B3A3,
    -2px 11px 0 #51B3A3,
    -3px 13px 0 #51B3A3,
    -3px 14px 0 #51B3A3,
    -3px 16px 0 #51B3A3,
    -3px 17px 0 #51B3A3,
    -4px 19px 0 #51B3A3,
    -4px 20px 0 #51B3A3,
    -4px 22px 0 #51B3A3,
    -4px 23px 0 #51B3A3,
    -4px 25px 0 #51B3A3,
    -4px 26px 0 #51B3A3,
    -5px 28px 0 #51B3A3,
    -5px 29px 0 #51B3A3;
}
```

[image]

[<kbd>3D DEMO with text-shadow only</kbd>](http://jsfiddle.net/kougiland/7BkQ6/1/)

you can then ajust it as you like!

Answer (score 1):

I think [this](http://simurai.com/lab/2010/07/26/tilt-shift/) is what you're referring to ([Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/emturano/yh6BG/)). The transform selector is going to be your friend in this situation, i.e. `transform: rotate(6.5deg) rotateX(188deg) skewX(-25deg)`.

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper" contenteditable="true" spellcheck="false">
  <p>Where</p>
  <p>are the</p>
  <p>trees</p>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Yanone+Kaffeesatz:bold);

/* Global ------------------------------------------------------ */

html {
  height: 100%;
  font: 62.5%/1 "Lucida Sans Unicode","Lucida Grande",Verdana,Arial,Helvetica,sans-serif;
  background: url(http://s.cdpn.io/79/glow.png) no-repeat center center,
    url(http://s.cdpn.io/79/tilt-shift.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  background-size: auto, cover;
}

body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: hsla(30,20%,95%,.9);
}


/* Wrapper ------------------------------------------------------ */

#wrapper {
  position: relative;
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: bold;
  font-family: "Yanone Kaffeesatz", "Lucida Grande", Lucida, Verdana, sans-serif;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 600px;
  padding: 7em 0;
  background: url(http://s.cdpn.io/79/tilt-shift.jpg) no-repeat center center;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: inset 0 -1px 0  hsla(0,0%,0%,.2), 0 21px 8px -12px rgba(0,0,0,.2);
  perspective: 350;
}

#wrapper:focus {
  outline: none;
}


#wrapper p {
  font-size: 10em;
  margin: 0;
  color: #fff;
  text-transform: uppercase;
  letter-spacing: 0.03em;
  text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0 20px 80px;
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-in; /* only WebKit because of performance */
}


/* Hover ------------------------------------------------------ */

#wrapper:hover p {
  color: hsla(0,0%,0%,0);
  transform: rotate(6.5deg) rotateX(28deg) skewX(-4deg);
  -webkit-transition: -webkit-transform .1s ease-out; /* only WebKit because of performance */
}

#wrapper:hover p:nth-child(1) {
  font-size: 9em;
  text-shadow: #fff 0 0 10px, 
    #fff 0 4px 3px, #ddd 0 9px 3px,  #ccc 0 12px 1px, 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 14px 5px, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0 20px 10px,
    rgba(0,0,100,0.2) 0 15px 80px;
  text-indent: 0.3em;
}

#wrapper:hover p:nth-child(2) {
  font-size: 10em;
  text-shadow: #fff 0 0 1px, 
    #eee 0 4px 3px, #ddd 0 9px 3px,  #ccc 0 12px 1px, 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 14px 3px, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0 20px 10px,
    rgba(0,0,100,0.2) 0 15px 80px;
}

#wrapper:hover p:nth-child(3) {
  font-size: 11em;
  text-shadow: #fff 0 0 2px, 
    #fff 0 4px 5px, #ddd 0 9px 5px,  #ccc 0 12px 10px, 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 14px 5px, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0 20px 10px,
    rgba(0,0,100,0.2) 0 15px 80px;
}


/* Middle ------------------------------------------------------ */

#wrapper p:nth-child(2):hover {
  text-shadow: #fff 0 -5px 1px, 
    #eee 0 -1px 3px, #ddd 0 4px 3px,  #ccc 0 7px 1px, 
    rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 15px 5px, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0 20px 10px,
    rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 15px 80px;
}

#wrapper p:nth-child(2):active {
  text-shadow: rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 14px 5px, rgba(0,0,0,0.1) 0 20px 10px,
    rgba(0,0,0,0.2) 0 15px 80px;
}

#wrapper p::selection {
  background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get an aproximate result setting a rotation with perspective:

```
display: inline-block;
-webkit-transform: perspective(200px) rotateX(20deg);
-webkit-transform-origin: 30% bottom;
transform: perspective(60px) rotateX(23deg);
transform-origin: 30% bottom;
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/RHxVr/6/)

I set the display to inline-block so that the perspective is centered, otherwise it is skewed.

[image: result]