# Image transformation inside SVG

Tags: image, svg

I need to render cube with some textures. I think SVG facilities is enough, but I can't tune *transform* function to apply appropriate transformation, especially fro top one square

[image]

Can you help me with that?

Comment: Here is the perfect answer from the master of transformations @ Ana. I hope that you will find there an answer to your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/14421939/7394871

Comment: SVG does not support non-affine transforms. You'd need CSS 3d transforms here.

Comment: @RobertLongson , it is possible using matrixes, I just do not exactly understand how it works https://codepen.io/atomAltera/pen/gXvROE?editors=1000

Comment: As I already said a 3d cube created by transforms is not possible using matrices because it would require non-affine transforms.